# Dissolving a TIN using python/ogr binding

Tags: python, ogr, dissolve, union

I have a TIN model where I remove some of the triangles (see fig. 1). Most of the triangles touch on one edge, some on one vertice. I would now like to generate a polygon shapefile containing the remaining triangles, dissolved into one polygon (of multiple rings, see fig. 2).

[image]

Fig 1. - TIN with some triangles removed. Vertices of touching triangles are *exactly* identical, no sliver polygons.

[image]

Fig. 2 - Note, that this is only **one** polygon with a single line in the attribute table

Pictures were made by using the QGIS "Vector-->Geoprocessing Tools-->Dissolve" tool.
Is this possible with the ogr python bindings?
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from osgeo import ogr

tri = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
tri.AddPoint(0,0)
tri.AddPoint(0,1)
tri.AddPoint(1,1)
tri.CloseRings()
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(tri)

tri2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
tri2.AddPoint(1,1)
tri2.AddPoint(0,1)
tri2.AddPoint(0,4)
poly2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly2.AddGeometry(tri2)

poly.Union(poly2) # returns None
poly.Intersect(poly2) # returns False
poly.Touches(poly2) # returns False (?)
poly.Disjoint(poly2) # returns False
```

I'm missing something like `poly.Dissolve()`, maybe used on a `ogr.wkbGeometryCollection`?

Comment: I guess you just forgot to close the second ring, in your case with `tri2.CloseRings()` , but the method you are looking for is `ogr.Geometry.Union()` as you tried in your code (or maybe `UnionCascaded()`). Anyway with second ring closed, your example work perfectly.

`In [3]: union_poly = poly.Union(poly2)

In [4]: union_poly.ExportToWkt()
Out[4]: 'POLYGON ((0 0 0,0 1 0,0 4 0,1 1 0,0 0 0))`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks. Would you mind posting as an answer, so I can accept it? (For reference: with a third triangle only connected on one vertice, this will create a `MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0 0,0 1 0,0 2 0,1 1 0,0 0 0)),((1 1 0,2 2 0,2 0 0,1 1 0)))`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As asked by the OP, I put this in answer. The problem wasn't with the method used, as **`ogr.Geometry.Union()`** is the appropriate one but with the second polygon which was not closed.
It can be done with :
`tri2.CloseRings()`
or by repeating the first point :
`tri2.AddPoint(1,1)`
If there is many features to dissolve (like the entire layer) it can be done with `UnionCascaded()` which is supposed to provide significant time savings compared to an iterative union.

Comment: I can confirm the significantly lower runtime of `UnionCascaded()`. It also helps if you don't dissolve the polygons one-by-one, but rather in a binary tree fashion.